# How do I install the " FourierSeries` " package?

Tags: numerical-integration, packages, fourier-analysis, numerical-value

Can anyone tell me where are the packages for Wolfram Mathematica 11.2 ? How do I load them?

Comment: The related information can be easily found by searching `FourierSeries\`` in the document. (The document can be opened by pressing **F1** key. ) The online edition is here: [Compatibility/tutorial/FourierSeries](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Compatibility/tutorial/FourierSeries.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mathematica automatically loads much of the functionality of the Wolfram Language on opening, unlike other languages which often only provide base functionality until packages are loaded/imported.

For special packages like the one you mention, they can be loaded in at least two ways:

```
Needs["FourierSeries`"]
```

or

```
<<FourierSeries`
```

See [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FourierSeries/tutorial/FourierSeries.html) page to learn more about loading and using the `` FourierSeries` `` package and the functions it includes.

The `` FourierSeries` `` package seems to mostly include numerical versions of the Fourier functions that are built-in such as `NFourierCosTransform` vs. `FourierCosTransform`. If you prefer the exact versions, you shouldn't need to load the package at all.

Comment: Many (most?) of those functions are now in the [Wolfram Function Repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/). Possibly they will migrate to Mathematica as System` functions (this is under consideration).